# How can I have full-height Tabs inside of a Toolbar using material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to have a fixed header where on the right side should be tabs. The `<Toolbar />` component is responsible for the responsiveness of the block but doesn't allow for *stretched* tabs so easily.

https://codesandbox.io/s/jv8v6vwqpv

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is that the [Toolbar](https://material-ui-next.com/api/toolbar/) responsively changes its height and the [Tabs](https://material-ui-next.com/api/tabs/) and [Tab](https://material-ui-next.com/api/tab/) component do not (Tabs sets a `min-height` of 48px in its `root` class, Tab sets a height in its `root` class).

Fortunately, the behavior `Toolbar` uses is available in a theme mixin, so you can create classes that also use this logic:

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  fullHeight: {
    ...theme.mixins.toolbar,
  },
});
```

This will create a class that has the same responsive height logic used in the `Toolbar` component.  Using [withStyles](https://material-ui-next.com/guides/typescript/#usage-of-withstyles), you can make this class accessible to your component:

```js
import { withStyles } from "material-ui/styles";

// ...

export default withStyles(styles)(Header);
```

This will add a `classes` prop, which is an object containing a string attribute for each class defined in the object provided to `withStyles`.  You can apply this to the `Tabs` component and each `Tab` component by [overriding their *root* classes](https://material-ui-next.com/customization/overrides/#overriding-with-classes) to ensure that they fill the `AppBar`:

```js
  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <AppBar>
        <Toolbar>
          <Grid container alignItems="center" justify="space-between">
            <Grid item>
              <Typography color="inherit" variant="title">
                BackTube
              </Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Tabs classes={{ root: classes.fullHeight }} onChange={this.changeTab} value={this.state.currentTab}>
                <Tab classes={{ root: classes.fullHeight }} icon={<Magnify />} value="search" />
                <Tab classes={{ root: classes.fullHeight }} icon={<FormatListBulleted />} value="lists" />
                <Tab classes={{ root: classes.fullHeight }} icon={<Settings />} value="settings" />
              </Tabs>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    );
```

Please note that the above solution was written for MUI v1 beta.

---

UPDATED 5/2022: The same thing can be accomplished in MUI 5, here is a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/full-height-tabs-demo-for-mui-5-zn5pep)

Comment: That does it thanks. Though I don't see how I could have thought of looking for a theme mixin. Did you just look at `<Toolbar />`'s source and noticed the inclusion there in the first place?

Comment: Also, any reason why you're not directly passing `classes` directly? Like this specifically: https://ptpb.pw/H2Rf

Comment: I ran into a similar problem before the mixin existed and was pretty happy to see it in the release notes a few beta releases back.  The reason I am not passing classes is because I wanted to override the component’s root class with the fullHeight class.  I could pass classes if the only class defined was root and I was only interested in overriding root.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification. Now, how could I add Material-UI classes following `<Toolbar />` responsive implementation to a custom-made component, or more generally an element that doesn't implement `root` in the first place?

Comment: You can define the class in the same manner and set that component's `className` property.  The `classes` technique is only a way of overriding the default style of material-ui components.

Comment: Thanks for demonstrating the use of Grid too.

Comment: how to do this in material v5?

Comment: @Normal I've added an updated codesandbox to the answer.  Basically you use `styled` to access the theme and create a styled version of `Tabs` and `Tab`

Comment: Kindly update your example. The code is not running at the moment @KenGregory.

Comment: The taab height is 64px. How do we make it responsive and set the height to 48px on landscape?

Comment: @WachagaMwaura The original answer was for MUI v1 beta.  In May of 2022 I updated this answer with a codesandbox that works with MUI v5 which uses a nearly identical approach, apart from the API changes.  Look at the codesandbox.

Comment: @a2441918 Look at the codesandbox.  It uses the toolbar mixin to set the height.  The MUI toolbar's responsive height is controlled by this mixin, so allowing the tab to follow and be sized identically to the toolbar will cause it to be resized appropriately based on device orientation and viewport size.

Comment: @KenGregory Thanks. I am able to resize and see 56 and 64px, but unable to get the 48px. Is there any way to get it?

Comment: @a2441918 Interesting.  Same issue exists in the MUI Docs for appbar.  For some reason a min-width: 600px media-query is taking precedence over the landscape media-query that sets it as 48px.  You may need to investigate this in MUI's code and submit an issue.